# characters from a stream

Tags: file, stream

this question was asked in an interview..

assume your computer is reading characters one by one from a stream (you don't know the length of the stream before ending). Note that you have only one character of storage space (so you cann't save the characters you've read to a something like a strong). When you've finished reading you should return a character out of the stream with equal probability.

how to approach this problem?? any idea??

any way to slove this??

Answer (score 5):

It's one of those tricks that you either know or don't:

Take the first character, with probability 1/2 take the next one, otherwise keep the first one, with probability 1/3 take the next one, otherwise keep, etc.

It works because every time you pick the *n* th char with probability of *1/n*, or keep the previous one (that had probability *1/(n-1)* to be there) with probability *(1-n)/n*, and the *1-n* s cancel.

Comment: just to be picky: where do you store `n` ? :-)

Comment: @Andre Holzner you can be even more picky and ask how do you generate a random number without using up any storage space, or how do you access the stream without needing storage space for the reference or pointer to the stream object.

Comment: @Andre Holzner more seriously, besides memory for the `char` and function calls to the stream and random number generator, this method requires storage of a single `double` representing the probability of taking or keeping. It can be updated as p = 1/((1/p)+1).